# How do I change target framework of existing Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, downgrade, target-framework

I have an existing project built in Visual Studio 2012 with VC++, which works fine on Windows 7 or higher versions. But when running on Windows XP, it gives an error that the application needs .NET framework v4.0 or higher to run. I am unable to install .NET Framework v4.0 on that system either.

So, the problem is that I want to downgrade my project's Target Framework Version, and I could not find any way to do it in Visual Studio 2012 - Windows Forms Application project.

Is there an alternate or better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must compile two applications, one for Windows 7 or higher and one for lower than Windows 7.

For changing your application .NET Framework follow the below address

> [On Menu Bar]
>
> Project -> "Your Application Name" Properties -> Application

And change

> "Target Framework"

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its a VC++ Winforms project, and there is no `Application` tab in project properties.

Comment: Oh Sory I Think This Can Help You http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff770576.aspx